# Comparing assembly dependencies

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have a referenced a.dll v2

I load a random.dll with a dependency on  a.dll v1 with Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

I wish to know if there is a way to get the list of assemblies/version on which the original random.dll required. So that I may check to see if it will work with the latest V2 and decide to load classes from it.

Comment: A manual way to check is by using JetBrain's dotPeek free application.

Comment: I was hoping to do a simple currentversion != assemblydependency version check in code.

Answer (score 1):

LoadFrom will try and load all the dependencies.  You might want to use [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't try and load everything referenced to the assembly, you can then use [GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the list of assemblies referenced.  To get the version of an assembly you'll need [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In order to achieve this i would have to load it in a separate app-domain., I Was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: You don't need a seperate app-domain, Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom does not load the assembly and it's referenced assemblies into the AppDomain. It simply loads the assembly manifest to allow you to get the list of dll's referenced to it.  LoadFrom loads the assembly and all it's referenced assemblies into the app domain and will fail if this is not possible due to incompatible versions